# Is it possible to test whether a user's browser/OS supports a given type of link using javascript?

Tags: javascript, mailto, url-scheme

Is it possible to test whether a user's OS/browser supports a given url scheme using javascript (or anything else)?

For example, mailto: isn't setup on most user's computer that only use webmail.  Would it be possible to somehow catch attempts to click a mailto link and pop up a more descriptive explanation than the browser error message?

Comment: Not that it helps you here, but some browsers (like Firefox) allow users to configure "mailto" links to go to their webmail, so even if they don't have a (non-webmail) email client they're OK.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to be able to help users on such browsers who don't have mailto configured to be able to setup their webmail to handle mailto, but it's tough because I don't know how to find those users, and the users who don't have it setup are also the users that aren't going to go looking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Would it be possible to somehow catch attempts to click a mailto link and pop up a more descriptive explanation than the browser error message?*

I don't know that you can determine whether a browser supports mailto: links. But as for attaching logic to mailto links, you could cycle through the links on the page, and test their `href` value. If it begins with "mailto:" you could attach a popup upon clicking it.

```
var maillinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var (var i = 0; i < maillinks.length; i++) {
  var currentlink = maillinks[i];
  if (currentlink.href.substring(0,7) === "mailto:") {
    alert("Sorry. These aren't allowed.");
    return false;
  }
}
```

The only real solution I can think to this problem is to host your own contact page, providing a small form that the user can submit.

Comment: But unfortunately, it looks like this would popup the disabled alert for both users that do support mailto and those that don't.

Comment: @williamjones: It wasn't mean to be a copy/paste solution. Only a demonstrating of attaching logic to mailto links. The real solution is to create your own contact page, and provide a small form that can be submitted through the site, rather than a local email client.

Answer (score 2):

In the general case — I don't think so.

In the specific case of mailto: — no.

To solve the problem you need to describe you need to know if the user has a configured email client, not if the browser supports mailto:. Most browsers support mailto:, and if the user doesn't have a configured client — it still 'works' (by starting the email client and prompting the user to configure it).

Comment: I've tried it on IE and Firefox on a computer without mailto: configured.  On IE8, it pops up a message, "Could not perform this operation because the default mail client is not properly installed."  Not too helpful for a user who only has webmail.  On Firefox clicking the link seems to just do nothing, with no feedback as to what the problem is.